# Android onRestart app problem

Tags: android, onresume, application-restart

Hi everytime I install app, open it than close it with back button and than again reopen it I get the same error:

```
05-05 10:49:35.453: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5118): java.lang.IllegalStateException: The content of the adapter has changed but ListView did not receive a notification. Make sure the content of your adapter is not modified from a background thread, but only from the UI thread. [in ListView(2131361820, class android.widget.ListView) with Adapter(class com.TVSpored.ChannelItemAdapter)]
```

I have read that I have to make onRestart function ([LINK](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onRestart%28%29))... but I have no idea how to handle it...

onCreate function do the following things:

1. set layout
2. set all necessary objects (ProgressDialog, ArrayList, ChannelItemAdapter, channelDBAdapter)
3. Loads data in asynctask: `new LoadChannels().execute(channelItem);`

As I have said before it work perfectly onStart and when browsing the app... but when leaving the app and restart it, it always crushes...

Thanks for your help!

---

Added code:

```
protected ArrayList<ToDoItem> doInBackground(ArrayList<ToDoItem>... passing) 
{

    cItems = passing[0]; //get passed arraylist
    toDoListCursor = channelDBAdapter. getAllToDoItemsCursor();
    startManagingCursor(toDoListCursor);
    channelItem.clear();
    if (toDoListCursor.moveToFirst())
    do 
    { 
      String task = toDoListCursor.getString(toDoListCursor.getColumnIndex(ToDoDBAdapter.KEY_NAME));
      String created = toDoListCursor.getString(toDoListCursor.getColumnIndex(ToDoDBAdapter.KEY_EPG_NAME));
      int fav = toDoListCursor.getInt(toDoListCursor.getColumnIndex(ToDoDBAdapter.KEY_FAV));
      int id = toDoListCursor.getInt(toDoListCursor.getColumnIndex(ToDoDBAdapter.KEY_EPG_ID));
      int ch_type = toDoListCursor.getInt(toDoListCursor.getColumnIndex(ToDoDBAdapter.KEY_CH_CHTYPE_ID));
      int country = toDoListCursor.getInt(toDoListCursor.getColumnIndex(ToDoDBAdapter.KEY_CH_COU_ID));
      ToDoItem newItem = new ToDoItem(task, created, fav, id, ch_type, country);
      channelItem.add(0, newItem);
    } 
    while(toDoListCursor.moveToNext());


    return cItems; //return result
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the stack trace you have provided, it seems you modify the content of your ListView Adapter outside of the UI thread. I think you should have a look at your ASyncTask to be sure that you perform modifications on your adapter only on methods that are executed in the UI thread (not in doInBackground for example).

See [ASyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

Comment: I have added a code from asyncTask above in my question ... I do the modifications ... but that is the point of asyncTask...

Comment: It is the purpose of an AsyncTask to perform heavy task that would slow down the main thread. Thus, the `doInBackground` method is executed on a separate thread but an adapter cannot be updated from a different thread than the UI one.

Prepare your modifications in the doInBackground method, but modify the header in the `onPostExecute` method and you will avoid throwing this exception.

Comment: great! Nice help I got the point now and happily repairing everything! Thanks!